# CSS and Javascript in .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

Dear all I am following a tutorial on youtube.com https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dq_hDsHbkM. In html(.html) file the code works perfectly when I follow the tutorial. It show how to make popup menu with Javascript and css. Is it possible to use .cshtml in an MVC application without the use of bootstrap or downloaded files from nuget packages? I want to be a able to code my own dialog box, with a form in it. Sorry I am quite new to javascript. Thanks in advance
Here is what I am trying to do in .cshtml file

```
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="openPopMenu()">
    Toggle popup menu!!
</button>
<div id="popup_bg">
    <div id="popup_main_div">
        <p id="javascript_magic">
            This is the magic of Javascript
        </p>
        <p id="javascript_desc">
            Learn how to create this professional <br /> popup menu with Javascript in the video!!1
        </p>
        <div id="close_popup_div" title="Close this popup menu" onclick="closePopupMenu()">
            <p>
                X
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mypopupDiv = document.getElementById("popupdialog");

    function openPopupMenu() {
        mypopupDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    function closePopupMenu() {
        mypopupDiv.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

My CSS file is as follows

```
#popupdialog {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
}

#popup_main_div {
position:fixed;
width:800px;
height:500px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: white;
left:50%;
margin-left:-400px;
top: 50%;
margin-top:-250px;
}

#javscript_magic {
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
background-color:lightyellow;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#javascript_desc {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: A quick Google search for "cshtml" suggests you're talking about ASP.NET MVC Framework so I've added such tag; feel free to correct it yourself if I'm wrong. Remember that Stack Overflow covers all programming languages and has a lot of traffic so it's always important to be specific in order to call the attention of users with the appropriate skills ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript was looking for a #popupdialog div which didn't exist in your HTML. Your button was trying to run a function called "openPopMenu" which needed to be changed to "openPopupMenu"

```js
var mypopupDiv = document.getElementById("popupdialog");

    function openPopupMenu() {
        mypopupDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    function closePopupMenu() {
        mypopupDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
#popupdialog {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
}

#popup_main_div {
position:fixed;
width:800px;
height:500px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: white;
left:50%;
margin-left:-400px;
top: 50%;
margin-top:-250px;
}

#javscript_magic {
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
background-color:lightyellow;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#javascript_desc {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="button" onclick="openPopupMenu()">
    Toggle popup menu!!
</button>
<div id="popupdialog">
  <div id="popup_bg">
      <div id="popup_main_div">
          <p id="javascript_magic">
              This is the magic of Javascript
          </p>
          <p id="javascript_desc">
              Learn how to create this professional <br /> popup menu with Javascript in the video!!1
          </p>
          <div id="close_popup_div" title="Close this popup menu" onclick="closePopupMenu()">
              <p>
                  X
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```